# pd.read_csv not correctly parsing date/month field when set parse_date = ['column name']

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas, date-format

I ran in to this bug while trying to parse the few dates through parse_dates of `pandas.read_csv()`. In the following code snippet, I'm trying to parse dates that have format `dd/mm/yy` which is resulting me an improper conversion. For some cases, the date field is considered as month and vice versa.

To keep it simple, for some cases `dd/mm/yy` get converted to `yyyy-dd-mm` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Case 1:

```
  04/10/96 is parsed as 1996-04-10, which is wrong.
```

Case 2:

```
  15/07/97 is parsed as 1997-07-15, which is correct.
```

Case 3:

```
  10/12/97 is parsed as 1997-10-12, which is wrong.
```

Code Sample

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('date_time.csv') 
print 'Data in csv:'
print df
print df['start_date'].dtypes

print '----------------------------------------------'

df = pd.read_csv('date_time.csv', parse_dates = ['start_date'])
print 'Data after parsing:'
print df
print df['start_date'].dtypes
```

Current Output

```
----------------------
Data in csv:
----------------------
  start_date
0   04/10/96
1   15/07/97
2   10/12/97
3   06/03/99
4     //1994
5   /02/1967
object
----------------------
Data after parsing:
----------------------
   start_date
0 1996-04-10
1 1997-07-15
2 1997-10-12
3 1999-06-03
4 1994-01-01
5 1967-02-01
datetime64[ns]
```

Expected Output

```
----------------------
Data in csv:
----------------------
   start_date
0   04/10/96
1   15/07/97
2   10/12/97
3   06/03/99
4     //1994
5   /02/1967
object
----------------------
Data after parsing:
----------------------
  start_date

0 1996-10-04
1 1997-07-15
2 1997-12-10
3 1999-03-06
4 1994-01-01
5 1967-02-01
datetime64[ns]
```

More Comments:

I could use `date_parser` or `pandas.to_datetime()` to specify the proper format for date. But in my case, I have few date fields like `['//1997', '/02/1967']` for which I need to convert `['01/01/1997','01/02/1967']`. The `parse_dates` helps me in converting those type of date fields to the expected format without making me to write extra line of code.

Is there any solution for this?

Bug Link @GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13063

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest 0.18 version of pandas? Is the issue still there?

Comment: Have you tried setting `infer_datetime_format` to `True`?

Comment: I have the exact same problem! My temporary solution was to read the values from an Excel file (instead of CSV), where the dates are parsed according to the local settings of the system, but I know this isn't a solution that suits most developers. You get correct dates when day > 12, since pandas realizes it can't be a month value.

Comment: Try setting dayfirst=True. I'm testing this now.

Comment: Yeah the default setting is for mm/dd I think. I don't know how to change it though.

Comment: This isn't a bug. `read_csv` uses the [`parse`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) function from dateutil by default. With this function, precedence is given to the MM-DD-YYYY format in the case of ambiguous dates.

Comment: @FabioLamanna It give the same output for version 0.18

Comment: @IanS It produces the same result after adding `infer_datetime_format` as well

Comment: Exactly @Shovalt. Okay I will test!

Comment: @ajcr  I assume there is definitely a bug with the parser. Like Shovalt mentioned, when DD <= 12, the parser gives us wrong conversion. Refer Case #1 and Case # 3. Otherwise it produces the right conversion as in Case #2. If you are saying parser Case #1 and #2 are right as it is in MM-DD-YYYY format, then the result produced by parser in Case #3 is wrong as it in DD-MM-YYYY. Isn't bug? The parser has to give us only one proper format which is not happening with this case.

Comment: As @ajcr said, this is *not* a bug. There just exist a wide variety of date formats, and it is not possible to parse all formats correctly by default without specifying extra parameters (like dayfirst in this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version pandas `0.18.0` you can add parameter `dayfirst=True` and then it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""start_date
04/10/96
15/07/97
10/12/97
06/03/99
//1994
/02/1967
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),  parse_dates = ['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
  start_date
0 1996-10-04
1 1997-07-15
2 1997-12-10
3 1999-03-06
4 1994-01-01
5 1967-02-01
```

Another solution:

You can parsing with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with different parameters `format` and `errors='coerce'` and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')
print date1
0   1996-10-04
1   1997-07-15
2   1997-12-10
3   1999-03-06
4          NaT
5          NaT
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
print date2
0          NaT
1          NaT
2          NaT
3          NaT
4          NaT
5   1967-02-01
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

date3 = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='//%Y', errors='coerce')
print date3
0          NaT
1          NaT
2          NaT
3          NaT
4   1994-01-01
5          NaT
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
print date1.combine_first(date2).combine_first(date3)
0   1996-10-04
1   1997-07-15
2   1997-12-10
3   1999-03-06
4   1994-01-01
5   1967-02-01
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . That's cool. :) I appreciate your effort. I wasn't aware of `dayFirst = True`. But I don't understand why there has to be another parameter to get the right format of date. Wouldn't be better if `parse_dates` could process it properly?

Comment: Hard question, I think `ajcr` as developer of `pandas` can explain better. But I think it is about performance.