# How to remove rows if certain condition is met (Python)

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe by merging 2 data frames and dropping duplicate rows. Is there a command which allows me to further filter this dataframe by deleting rows were a specific column's date is lower than today's date/ expired?

Comment: `df = df[~(df['Date'] < date_today)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), but need invert condition - filter values which are today and higher:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-08-01', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (df)
        Date  a
0 2017-08-01  0
1 2017-08-02  1
2 2017-08-03  2
3 2017-08-04  3
4 2017-08-05  4
5 2017-08-06  5
6 2017-08-07  6
7 2017-08-08  7
8 2017-08-09  8
9 2017-08-10  9
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['Date'] >= pd.datetime.today()]
print (df1)
        Date  a
2 2017-08-03  2
3 2017-08-04  3
4 2017-08-05  4
5 2017-08-06  5
6 2017-08-07  6
7 2017-08-08  7
8 2017-08-09  8
9 2017-08-10  9

date_today = pd.datetime.today()
df1 = df.query("Date >=@date_today")
print (df1)
        Date  a
2 2017-08-03  2
3 2017-08-04  3
4 2017-08-05  4
5 2017-08-06  5
6 2017-08-07  6
7 2017-08-08  7
8 2017-08-09  8
9 2017-08-10  9
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I started using Python yesterday so excuse my lack of knowledge but surely if use a query I will be setting 'today's date' at a fixed value. This means that if I have look at the database next week but one of the entries has expired, the dataframe will not reflect this. Also, what is the point of changing the code everyday to reflect the today's new date -  if this is the solution I may as well just remove the data from the database directly.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused - `pd.datetime.today()` generate every day `date` - e.g. tomorrow `2017-09-02`. It is problem?

Comment: Sorry, I understand you now. I didn't know the pd.datetime.today() command.

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I am still having some problems, maybe you can help? In order to remove rows based on a specific date I need to convert all my column values into the same datetime format. This is where I have the problem. Some dates are like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' but others are in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format. How do I standardize these 2 formats so they are the same?

Comment: It is not so easy, but second solution should works - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36998752/2901002)